# PHP Function Array values not changing

Tags: php, arrays

Ive created a function that takes an array as a parameter and changes all values to 4, but it doesn't work and i don't understand why. Really bothering me, could use help thank you!

```
$cup3 = array (1,4,3,5,7,2);
roll($cup3);
print_r($cup3);

function roll($array)
{
    foreach($array as &$value)
    {
        $value = 4;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Output: (1,4,3,5,7,2) instead of all 4s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either pass by reference `&$array` to edit `$cup3` directly:

```
roll($cup3);
print_r($cup3);

function roll(&$array)
{
    foreach($array as &$value)
    {
        $value = 4;
    }
}
```

Or use the return from the function:

```
$cup3 = roll($cup3);
print_r($cup3);

function roll($array)
{
    foreach($array as &$value)
    {
        $value = 4;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!

Comment: The key insight here is that the array is passed in by value, unlike an object that would be passed in by reference.  If you want the array's modifications in the function body to persist beyond the function, you'd have to explicitly pass it in by reference, like in @AbraCadaver 's first example.

Comment: important lesson that I will remember. gotta remember the basics.